# Returning a local BIG PDF to be viewed with PHP isn't working properly

Tags: php, pdf

I figured out how to return the PDF correctly, however it takes 5 - 20 seconds (depending on file size) for Google Chrome/Microsoft Edge/Internet Explorer to show a progress bar.

```
$file = 'http://foobar.com/data/users/1/uploads/2342343/signed/protected.pdf';
$filename = 'protected';
$headers  = get_headers($file, 1);

$fsize    = $headers['Content-Length'];


header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

This is taking way to long for it to actually display a result because the loading doesn't fire fast enough.  What am I missing? Am I doing something wrong to cause the progress bar to not immediately show to start loading the PDF?  Is the get_headers actually downloading the file first?

Or what is the best way to return a BIG PDF in the fastest way possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the file in a stream fashion, flushing the content parts to the client.

I did some code to read in a stream fashion these days, but I was using the [OCI-Lob::read](http://php.net/manual/en/oci-lob.read.php), because my PDF was stored in an Oracle database. I think your file may be stored in a different way, so you need a different implementation. In my case, I read the file contents 1MB each time. I was not working with flushing content to the client.

I'm not that expert in PHP, but I think you could take a look in the [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function to accomplish the loading progress.